# Using Boto to send SQS notifications for an MTurk hit

Tags: python, boto, amazon-sqs, mechanicalturk

I'm trying to set up SQS notifications for an MTurk HIT created using Boto. I'm able to create the HIT type, create a HIT with that type, create an SQS queue, and write to and read from the queue. I've also written the command that (I thought) would set notifications for the given HIT type. But no notifications are sent.

Any idea what's going on?

```py
print "Debugging..."

import boto
import boto.sqs
from boto.mturk.connection import MTurkConnection
from boto.mturk.question import QuestionContent, Question, QuestionForm, \
    Overview, AnswerSpecification, SelectionAnswer, FormattedContent, \
    FreeTextAnswer
import uuid

ACCESS_ID = 'REDACTED'
SECRET_KEY = 'REDACTED'
HOST = 'mechanicalturk.sandbox.amazonaws.com'

mtc = MTurkConnection(aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_ID,
                      aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
                      host=HOST)

print mtc.get_account_balance()

# --------------- DESIGN THE HIT -------------------

title = 'Give your opinion about a website ' + str(uuid.uuid4())
print title

description = ('Visit a website and give us your opinion about'
               ' the design and also some personal comments')
keywords = 'website, rating, opinions'

ratings = [
    ('Very Bad', '-2'),
    ('Bad', '-1'),
    ('Not bad', '0'),
    ('Good', '1'),
    ('Very Good', '1')
]

# ---------------  BUILD OVERVIEW -------------------

overview = Overview()
overview.append_field('Title', 'Give your opinion on this website')
overview.append(FormattedContent('hello'))

qc1 = QuestionContent()
qc1.append_field('Title', 'Your personal comments')

fta2 = FreeTextAnswer()

q = Question(identifier="comments",
             content=qc1,
             answer_spec=AnswerSpecification(fta2))

# --------------- BUILD THE QUESTION FORM -------------------

question_form = QuestionForm()
question_form.append(overview)
question_form.append(q)

# --------------- CREATE THE HIT -------------------

hit_type = mtc.register_hit_type(
    title,
    description,
    0.05,
    60*5,
    keywords=keywords,
    approval_delay=None,
    qual_req=None)[0]

print hit_type.HITTypeId

hit = mtc.create_hit(
    hit_type=hit_type.HITTypeId,
    questions=question_form,
    max_assignments=1,
    title=title,
    description=description,
    keywords=keywords,
    duration=60*5,
    reward=0.05)[0]

print hit
print dir(hit)
print hit.HITTypeId

sqs_connection = boto.sqs.connect_to_region(
    "us-west-2",
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_ID,
    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)

# Set up Amazon Simple Queue Service.
queue_name = "wallace_queue"
queue = sqs_connection.create_queue(queue_name)
sqs_connection.add_permission(
    queue,
    "MTurkSendMessage",
    "755651556756",
    "SendMessage")

m = boto.sqs.message.Message()
m.set_body("hello world.")
queue.write(m)

rs = queue.get_messages()
for m in rs:
    msg = m.get_body()
    print "got message:"
    print msg
    assert msg == "hello world."

# set up queue notifications
qrl = "https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/134127175127/" + queue_name
all_event_types = [
    "AssignmentAccepted",
    "AssignmentAbandoned",
    "AssignmentReturned",
    "AssignmentSubmitted",
    "HITReviewable",
    "HITExpired",
]
mtc.set_sqs_notification(
    hit.HITTypeId, qrl, event_types=all_event_types)

print "Done."
```

Answer (score 0):

You should go to your own queue on SQS's AWS console and add a new permission:

Effect: Allow

Principal: arn:aws:iam::755651556756:user/MTurk-SQS

Actions: SendMessage

Later on, you should build your HITType with your preferred notifications and your queue's url.

This way when you create a HIT request on mturk, the one and only valid user of Amazon Mechanical Turk "MTurk-SQS" will send your notifications messages from your mturk requester.sandbox account to your SQS queue.

Your might need to see these steps from [MTurkR's Notifications](https://github.com/leeper/MTurkR/wiki/Notifications).

Answer (score -1):

In case you are still struggling with this, there are some permissions you need to set in SQS to allow MTurk to send it messages. They are described here: [enter link description here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_NotificationReceptorAPI_SQSTransportArticle.html)